# Prove or disprove $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\|y_{k+1}-y_k\|<\infty$ if $y_{k+1}=\big(I_n-\frac{ax_kx_k^{\rm T}}{b+\|x_k\|^2}\big)y_k$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, vector-analysis

> For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $x_k,\ y_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and assume that 
>   \begin{equation}
> y_{k+1}=\left(I_n-\frac{ax_kx_k^{\rm T}}{b+\|x_k\|^2}\right)y_k,~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
> \end{equation}
>   where $a\in(0,1)$, and $b>0$. Prove or disprove by counterexample that 
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\|y_{k+1}-y_k\|<\infty.$$

---

I can show the summablity for the case where $n=1$: Since $a\in(0,1)$, it follows that
\begin{align}
|y_{k+1}|-|y_k|&=\left|1-\frac{ax_k^2}{b+x_k^2}\right||y_k|-|y_k|\\
&=-\frac{ax_k^2}{b+x_k^2}|y_k|,
\end{align}
which is nonpositive. Thus,
\begin{align}
0\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{ax_k^2}{b+x_k^2}|y_k|\leq\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(|y_{k}|-|y_{k+1}|\right)\leq |y_{0}|-\lim_{k\to\infty}|y_k|\leq |y_{0}|.
\end{align}
Since, in the above expression, the lower and upper bounds exist, it follows that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{ax_k^2}{b+x_k^2}|y_k|<\infty,
\end{equation}
Thus, it follws from (1) that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty|y_{k+1}-y_k|=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{ax_k^2}{b+x_k^2}|y_k|<\infty.
\end{equation}

---

I do not know how to extend this to the case where $n>1$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $$ y_{k+1} = \bigg(I - \frac{a}{b_k +1} x_kx_k^T \bigg) y_k$$
where $|x_k|=1,\ b_k>0,\ 0<a<1$. Here $x_kx_k^T$ is a projection.

So clearly $|y_{k+1}|\leq y_k$ and $L:=\sum_k\ |y_k-y_{k-1}|$ is
length of piecewise
broken curve.

(1) If $x_k \in \{ e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ where $e_i$
is a canonical
basis, then $L\leq \|y_0\|_1$.

(2) Extreme case : Assume that $a=1,\ b_k=0$ :

If $S_k$ is a radius $\frac{|y_k|}{2}$ sphere whose center is
$\frac{y_k}{2}$, then $y_{k+1}$ is any
point in $S_k$.

If $|y_0|=1$, then assume that $\angle\ (y_i,y_{i+1})=\theta_i$,
then $$ |y_{i+1}|=\cos\ \theta_i |y_i| =\prod_{k=0}^i\ \cos\
\theta_k
$$ and

$$  |y_i-y_{i+1}| =|y_i|\sin\ \theta_i = \sin\ \theta_i\prod_{k=0}^{i-1}\ \cos\
\theta_k $$

Hence $$ L =\sum_i\ \sin\ \theta_i\prod_{k=0}^{i-1}\ \cos\ \theta_k
$$

If $0<C<\theta_i<\frac{\pi}{2}-C$, then $L$ is finite. If $\theta_i\rightarrow 0$, then it depends on $\theta_i$ :

If $\sum_i\ \theta_i <\infty$, then $L$ is finite by the above calculation : $\{y_i\}$ can be viewed as enumeration of points in curve of finite length.

If $\sum_i\ \theta_i=\infty,\ \sum_i\ \theta_i^2<\infty$, then $L$
is infinite : As an example, it has an infinite turn around a fixed circle.

If $  \sum_i\ \theta_i= \sum_i\ \theta_i^2 =\infty$, then $L$ is
finite : $y_k$ goes to origin.

If $\theta_i\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\cos\ \theta_i\rightarrow 0$ so that $L$
 is finite.

(3) **general case can be covered by (2)** :

**Proof :** Let $Y=(I-x_k' (x_k')^T)X$ and $y_{k+1}= (I-A_k
x_kx_k^T)y_k,\ X=y_k ,\ 0<A_k<1$

Note that there is $x_k'$ s.t. $$ |Y-X |=|y_{k+1}-y_k|
$$ 
 Hence we have two piecewise broken curves : One is the curve in (2), we denote it as $y_k'$, and another is that of $y_k$.

Here $y_k'$ is plotted by $y_k$. If $y_k'$ is the origin, then in next
time, from $y_{k+1}$, we can not plot $y_{k+1}'$. So remaining thing is to show that $|Y|\geq |y_{k+1}|$.

Note that $\Delta oYX $ is a right triangle at $Y$ s.t. $y_{k+1}$ is
interior point of the triangle.

If we extend a segment $[Yy_{k+1}]$, then it intersect at $Z\in
[oX]$. Since $\Delta XYy_{k+1}$ is isosceles, then $\Delta XYZ$ is
acute triangle. Hence we complete the proof.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand your proof. Is your $x_k$ same as mine? Where does $|x_k|=1$ come from? What are cases (1) and (2)? Do you mean we only need to consider these 2 cases? What do you mean by extreme case? Why $a=0$ is not an extreme case? How does $x_k\in\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ imply finite $L$?

Comment: $a \frac{x_kx_k^T}{b +|x_k|^2} = a \frac{ \frac{x_k}{|x_k|} \frac{x_k^T}{|x_k|} }{b/|x_k|^2 +1}$ so that let $b_k =b/|x_k|^2>0$.

Comment: (1) Note that we diminish $y_i$ in direction $x_k$. If $x_k$ is in canonical basis, i.e., diminishing direction is fixed, then consider Manhattan metric $\|\ \|_1$. The union of line segment $[y_iy_{i+1}]$ is like calculating $\|\ \|_1$.

Comment: (2) Consider the map $v\mapsto (I-\frac{a}{b_k+1} x_kx_k^T)v$. This is not a orthogonal projection into the hyperplane $x_k^\perp$ (but similar) so that I deal the case of orthogonal projection, i.e., $a=1,\ b_k=0$.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for asking many questions. How does $|Y|\geq|y_{k+1}|$ imply summability? I am not familiar with these geometric concepts but obviously, this can be converted to an algebraic approach. I am still studying your answer but your comments help a lot.

Comment: I add more explanation.

Comment: These arguments do not imply $y_k$ converges. Do they?

Comment: Since $\sum_i \ |y_i-y_{i+1}|<\infty$, $y_k$ is bounded. And if it has two accumulation point, then $\sum_i \ |y_i-y_{i+1}| =\infty$ so that it converges.

Comment: Sorry, I am back to this problem. Could you please briefly explain how to religiously show that $L$ in (2) is finite if $\theta_i\to 0$ as $i\to\infty$? I understand that in this case $\prod_k^\infty \cos\theta_k$ exists.

Comment: You are right. I modified.

Comment: Thanks, now I do not understand as to how $\theta_i=1/i$ cannot happen.

Comment: I mean that $\sum_i\ \sin\ \theta_i =\infty$ may happen.

Comment: That implies we have no proof at the moment. Right?

Comment: Yes. But I edited so that this is a proof.

Comment: Thanks. In order to have a general proof, don't we need $L$ finite in (2)? We still have a case where $L$ is infinite in (2).

Comment: Yes. ($L$ is infinite iff there is a subsequence s.t. $\sum_i\ \theta_i=\infty >\sum_i\ \theta_i^2$. And such case exists, in fact)

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your help. I learned a lot.